# How to access a bloc's current state's property in the initState?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a global bloc that wraps the materiapApp widget and I am able to get the bloc inside my deep nested widget tree. However, I would like to access the current state's property.

```
  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    _internetConnectionBloc = BlocProvider.of<InternetConnectionBloc>(context); 
    //I am able to get the bloc but I would like to access it's current state's property

  }
```

States:

```
abstract class InternetConnectionState extends Equatable {
  const InternetConnectionState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InternetConnectionInitial extends InternetConnectionState {}

class InternetConnectionStatusUpdated extends InternetConnectionState {
  final InternetConnectionType connectionType;

  const InternetConnectionStatusUpdated(this.connectionType);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [connectionType];
}
```

I would like to access the `InternetConnectionStatusUpdated` state's `connectionType` property in the `initState` instead of `blocListener`in the build method.

Answer (score 1):

**try this in initState**

```
var connectionType = BlocProvider.of<InternetConnectionBloc>(context).state.connectionType;
```

Comment: I tried that before but it doesn't work, as the compiler doesn't know the state type during compile time, we cannot call `connectionType` and the build fails.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

```
 @override
 void initState() {

    super.initState();
    _internetConnectionBloc = BlocProvider.of<InternetConnectionBloc>(context); 
     final state = _internetConnectionBloc!.state; 
    if(state is InternetConnectionStatusUpdated){ // --> this way dart
     //analyze was able to understand the state type
      print(state.connectionType);
    }
  
 }
```